# complex square root inequality

Tags: complex-numbers

Let $z$ and $w$ denotes two complex numbers. I'm looking forward to finding a way to show that

$$
\min\{|\sqrt{z+w}+\sqrt{w}|,|\sqrt{z+w}-\sqrt{w}| \}\leq |z|(|z|+|w|)^{-1/2}
$$
where the $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is taking value on the principal branch.
Can someone give me a hint on proving this ?

Comment: There are two square roots of every nonzero complex number, so is the question to prove for both of them?

Comment: square root is taking value on principal branch

Comment: @Akababa The two square roots only differ by sign, and the LHS is invariant with respect to a sign change in either $\,\pm \sqrt{\,\cdot\,}\,$  square root, so in this case it doesn't really matter which value is chosen.

Comment: Yeah good point. pretty obvious in retrospect if you draw a parallelogram.

Answer (score 1):

The inequality does not hold true in general. For a counterexample, consider $\,z=1, w=-1\,$:

$$
\min\left\{\left|\sqrt{1+(-1)}+\sqrt{-1}\right|,\left|\sqrt{1+(-1)}-\sqrt{-1}\right| \right\} = |i| = 1 \,\color{red}{\gt}\, \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}= |1|\,\big(|1|+|-1|\big)^{-1/2}
$$